# Why should update Query condition fails

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have sql table as follow

```
id      position
------------
1       2
2       1
3       3
```

Now i wants to perform action that return result as follow

```
 id     position
    ------------
    1       1
    2       2
    3       3
```

So how can i do ?

Comment: remove the && condition and tell the output.

Comment: Use AND instead of && for sql

Comment: Because there's nothing to update? You don't have row with `id=1`? Row with `id=1` already has `pos=2`?

Comment: you don't need 2 conditions. just use  'where id=1' remove the second condition

Comment: //Query 2
 UPDATE `product` 
 SET pos='2' 
 WHERE id = 1

Comment: id is required in this case.

Comment: Are you sure that you posted the exact query? Despite the duplicated condition, this query would be valid.

Comment: see udpated question

Comment: you need to update values to match both columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two variables to store the `position`column values of ids having 1 and 2. Then use a `CASE` expression to update the table accordingly.

**Query**

```
set @a := (select `position` from `your_table_name` where id = 1);
set @b := (select `position` from `your_table_name` where id = 2);

update `your_table_name`
set `position` = (
    case `id` when 1 then @b else @a end
)
where `id` < 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

what is `pos` ?

Try this one `UPDATE table_name SET your_field_name= '2' WHERE id = 1`

Comment: pos defines position